# (Supabase, Next.js) remove the public prefix by default in my paths

Tags: sql, reactjs, next.js, supabase

I would like to get information using a function I created in supabase:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auth.get_mfa_factors(user_id uuid)
RETURNS TABLE (secret text) AS $$
SELECT secret
FROM auth.mfa_factors
WHERE auth.mfa_factors.user_id = get_mfa_factors.user_id
AND factor_type = 'totp';
$$ STABLE SQL LANGUAGE;
```

And I call this function in Next.js:

```
const { data: userCredentials, error: credentialsError } = await supabase
.rpc('auth.get_mfa_factors', { user_id: user.id });
```

but when I send a post method to get the data I get this response in postman:

```
{
    "message": "Connection failed",
    "error": "Could not find the function public.auth.get_mfa_factors(user_id) in the schema cache"
}
```

Anyway, I've tried a few solutions, but I always get public which gets prefixed in my path. how to remove supabase's default public prefix ?

Comment: Could you share the full details of the request you are making via postman?

Comment: is it possible that, instead of using a function with the auth prefix, you use a public function, but in the function, you set it to be a security definer, so that it can access the auth tables?